# A length and Size for each quantity & Type of product

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php Shopping cart - Size and length for each quantity of a type of product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987724/php-shopping-cart-size-and-length-for-each-quantity-of-a-type-of-product)

Hi i Previously posted this question here and some replies but still cant figure out whats messing my script up....

I Have a shopping cart on page order.php. Its a retail section for a company so that the stores can purchase dresses from that online section. So there are multiple dresses and people can chose any number of dresses. Furthermore on that shopping script there is a place to change the size and length of dresses.

Currently when you order a dress you can select single size and single length per order 
Ex : IF you order 4 Quantity of dress A you can select only one size and length for that dress A.

Now all i want to implement is When you order 4 quantity of dress A, you should be able to choose length and size for each quantity of Dress A means 4 Lengths and 4 Sizes. Maybe this sounds weird but that something i need very desperately

Following is the code :

Session Initialization

```
session_start();

//Create 'cart' if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }


//Add an item only if we have the threee required pices of information: name, price, qty
if (isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['qty']) && isset($_GET['size'])&& isset($_GET['length'])&& isset($_GET['code']) ){
//Adding an Item
//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
//Item name
'name' => $_GET['add'],
//Item Price
'price' => $_GET['price'],
//Qty wanted of item
'qty' => $_GET['qty'],

'size' => array_fill(0, $_GET['qty'], $_GET['size']),

    'length' => array_fill(0, $_GET['qty'], $_GET['length']),

'code' => $_GET['code']
);
```

Part which is supposed to update and store the values of quantity, size and length.

```
foreach ($_POST['items_qty'] as $itemID => $qty) {
//If the Qty is "0" remove it from the cart
if ($qty == 0) {
//Remove it from the cart
unset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]);
}
else if($qty >= 1) {
//Update to the new Qty
$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['qty'] = $qty;

}
foreach ($_POST['items_size'] as $itemID => $size) {
//If the Qty is "0" remove it from the cart
if($size >= 1) {
//Update to the new Qty
$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['size'] = $size;

}
}
foreach ($_POST['items_length'] as $itemID => $length) {
//If the Qty is "0" remove it from the cart

//Update to the new Qty
$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemID]['length'] = $length;


}
```

Thirdly the part that is supposed to display the values :

<

```
?php
//Print all the items in the shopping cart
foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
?>
<tr align="center" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">
<td><a href="?remove=<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">remove</a></td>
<td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
<td><input name="items_qty[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>
<td><?php echo $item['qty'] * $item['price']; ?></td>

<td><select name="items_size[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" value="<?php echo $item['size']; ?>" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_size" >
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $item['size']; ?>"><?php echo $item['size']; ?></option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="30">30</option>

</select>
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $item_id => $item)
{
    echo '<p>Name: ' . $item['name'] . ' for ' . $item['price'] . '$</p>';
    foreach($item['size'] as $j => $size)
    {
        echo '<p>#' . $j . ': size ' . $size . ', length ' . $item['length'][$j] . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
<?php
$order=strtotime("now");

if($cntry == "USA" || $cntry =="United States Of America" || $cntry == "America")
{
$price=100;
}
else
{
$price=200;
}

?>
<td><select name="items_length[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" select="<?php echo $item['length']; ?>" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_length" >
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $item['length']; ?>"><?php echo $item['length']; ?></option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="50">50</option>


</select>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $item_id => $item)
    {
        echo '<p>Name: ' . $item['name'] . ' for ' . $item['price'] . '$</p>';
        foreach($item['size'] as $j => $size)
        {
            echo '<p>#' . $j . ': size ' . $size . ', length ' . $item['length'][$j] . '</p>';
        }
    }
```

This part was suggested to me by one of the forum member.

Also after adding the following lines to item array (1st section)

```
'size' => array_fill(0, $_GET['qty'], $_GET['size']),

    'length' => array_fill(0, $_GET['qty'], $_GET['length']),
```

When i press update button after changing the quantity it doesnt update.. It stays at one...

Now i really dont know or understand where to add what code. I am confused. Please help me

Comment: [What have you tried??](http://whathaveyoutried.com) This is a lot of code, and no one wants to do the work for you for free. Please post only the code you have questions about, and what you have tried so far, and elaborate on `still cant figure out whats messing my script up....`. What you want to do does not sound weird, as it is a very common situation, but no one wants to do it all for you.

Comment: **Do not** repost unanswered questions.

Comment: Sorry about reposting this. I am not a very pro php developers and neither were my intentions to get anything done for free... I ll remove the whole code and add the part i believe is making issue. Sorry again

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your question you just posted the whole code you have and are asking people to debug it.

I understand your frustration, I have been there multiple times but you do not help your case with a copy paste. I tried to go through the code and there is no indentation, there is a myriad of header redirects and basically it is really difficult to debug it or even understand what is going on. I even tried editing it to make it more readable but after 10 minutes I gave up.

Split your code in smaller chunks and you will find the solution yourself

To your question: What you can do is either do some server side checking or client checking

Client checking:

- You can add 4 lines (qty 4) and allow the user to select the tize of each item. You can merge the quantities once you get the data from the user in the during the submit.
- You can add qty 4 of size 40 but also offer a button (again this is Javascript) that would remove one item from the quantity and create a new line item so that the user can add a new size.

Server checking:

- Have the user select the size and then once that is done offer a page with different sizes for each item of the order.

Which approach you take is up to you.

PS: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE consider changing your database access to `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` has been deprecated. There are plenty of resources on this site on how to do so.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I have edited the question and have posted the particular sections where i need help. Please help me :(